# select options tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form where I want a select drop-down list to show options 0-41.  I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
<%= f.select :years_together, 42.times do |year| %>
  <%= year %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

Actually, I want the select to show "Less than a year" for value zero and "More than 40" for value 41.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `options_for_select`:

```
<%= f.select :years_together, options_for_select(41.times { |year| year }) %>
```

Comment: looks like this worked:     <%= f.select :years_together, options_for_select(41.times.map { |year| year }) %>